# My friend sent me a strange text

Tags: cipher

Yesterday my friend sent me a really weird text. After that he wouldn't text me back or return my calls... Can you guys help me?

[image: image of phone texts]
<sub>(source: [i.pi.gy](https://i.pi.gy/9LDkV.jpg))</sub>

I've transcribed it to try to help...

> [Blue Yellow][Blue][Orange Green Indigo][Green] [Green Green][Violet Violet Red][Violet Violet Blue][Violet Violet Indigo][Red][Violet][Blue] [Violet Violet Blue][Blue][Violet Violet][Green] [Blue Yellow][Blue][Violet Blue][Green Green Blue Yellow]!

I think that each section of brackets might be a word, but I'm not sure.

Hint 1:

> My friend loves rainbows.

Hint 2:

> He likes to create conversion puzzles. E.g. numbers to letters.

Hint 3:

> My friend also likes math.

Comment: Liked this one! QUick note though, you don't really need to add any hints as soon as you post, once the post goes a few hours, maybe a few days, *then* starting adding hints. Nice puzzle though :)

Comment: To make things easier, I've abbreviated each of the colors: `[BY][B][OGI][G] [GG][VVR][VVB][VVI][R][V][B] [VVB][B][VV][G] [BY][B][VB][GGBY]!`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The message is

> HELD HOSTAGE, SEND HELP!

How the cipher works

> Take the corresponding position number for each colour (ROYGBIV = 1234567) and add up all the numbers in each bracket. Finally, convert to a letter using A1Z26.

So:

> Conversion tables:
>
> ```
> ROYGBIV
> 1234567
>
> A B C D E F G H I J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
> ```
>
> [BY] = [5+3] = [8] = H
> [B] = [5] = E
> [OGI] = [2+4+6] = [12] = L
> [G] = [4] = D
>
> [GG] = [4+4] = [8] = H
> [VVR] = [7+7+1] = [15] = O
> [VVB] = [7+7+5] = [19] = S
> [VVI] = [7+7+6] = [20] = T
> [R] = [1] = A
> [V] = [7] = G
> [B] = [5] = E
>
> [VVB] = [7+7+5] = [19] = S
> [B] = [5] = E
> [VV] = [7+7] = [14] = N
> [G] = [4] = D
>
> [BY] = [5+3] = [8] = H
> [B] = [5] = E
> [VB] = [7+5] = [12] = L
> [GGBY] = [4+4+5+3] = [16] = P
>  !
>
> HELD HOSTAGE SEND HELP!